# QEMU ARMv8-A Networking

Tags: linux, arm, qemu

I am using QEMU 6.2.0 (qemu-system-aarch64) on Ubuntu 20.04.1 system. I am running a armv8a, 64bit Linux guest using the command line as shown below.

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=2,virtualization=on -cpu cortex-a53 -nographic -smp 4 -m 4096 -kernel /home/linux-5.10.155/arch/arm64/boot/Image -netdev user,id=n1 -device e1000,netdev=n1
```

After the guest boots up, if I give *ifconfig -a* the following output is shown

```
# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:18:56:25  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Looks like no IP address is assigned to eth0. Manually setting the IP address (10.0.2.16 , as per this doc https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking) did not help.

I understand that this is a NAT configuration. Then I tried with tap (bridge) option as shown below.

```
$sudo qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=2,virtualization=on -cpu cortex-a53 -nographic -smp 4 -m 4096 -kernel /home/linux-5.10.155/arch/arm64/boot/Image -nic tap,model=e1000
```

This throws the error

```
qemu-system-aarch64: -nic tap,model=e1000: network script /etc/qemu-ifup failed with status 256
```

The */etc/qemu-ifup* script has execute permission.

My intention is to access Internet in the guest.

What might be wrong with configuration? Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: User-mode networking (as in your first example) shows the guest a fake DHCP server. Is your guest OS running a dhcp client to query it for the IP address and other information ?

Comment: PS: running QEMU as root is not a good idea -- if you want to use tap networking you should do something more sophisticated than that.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMaydell. Yes, the DHCP client was not running. The internet is available in the guest now.